# Protected/Private Inheritance Casting

Tags: c++, inheritance

I came across this issue accidentally when I was going over inheritance and up/down casting. Why is this not allowed (code is commented to show sections that are not allowed)? Now I can guess as to why it is not allowed but a factual answer would be great.

As for the code that *is* allowed, I know it is because **(Base*)** is a C-style cast which is essentially a **reinterpret_cast** in C++ which in turn means that in this case it will result in undefined behavior. Please correct me if I am wrong.

```
class Base
{
};

class Derived : public Base
{
};

class DerivedProt : protected Base
{
};

class DerivedPriv : private Base
{
};

int main()
{
  Base* a = new Derived();
  Base* b = new DerivedProt();  // Not allowed
  Base* c = new DerivedPriv();  // Not allowed

  Base* d = (Base*) new DerivedProt(); // Allowed but undefined behavior...?
  Base* e = (Base*) new DerivedPriv(); // Allowed but undefined behavior...?
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you are correct.

One thing to remember is that traditional OO principles such as the LSP only describe public inheritance.  Non-public inheritance falls in-between inheritance and composition, the base subobject is non-public like composition, but you can also take advantage of features which rely on inheritance, such as virtual functions.

Just like a composed subobject, however, only the class (or its descendants, in case of protected inheritance), can get the address of the subobject.

Answer (score 6):

The Standard explicitly specifies that C-style casts may perform this conversion. It's the only cast which C-style casts *can* do but no C++ cast can do. The results are not undefined a far as I know; it's just not allowed by any other cast.

Comment: Even if it's not undefined behavior, it's still an incredibly bad idea and should be avoided.  One thing that's very dangerous about this cast is that the compiler will try to do it even when there is no inheritance relationship and not even generate a warning.

Comment: I had to check with Comeau online to see if my compiler got this wrong.  Nope, reinterpret_cast<> can do this too.

Comment: @HansPassant But `reinterpret_cast` does not know or care about base classes. It cannot be used for up or down casts.